# Gas estimation error with 32000 error code

Tags: binance, chainlink

I can able to deploy on kovan network and get this running fine but cannot able to deploy on bsc testnet

tried with this RPC URL

https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/
Chain ID : 97

and also

RPC UrL : https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.binance.org:8545/
Chain ID : 97

but it didn't help.

Here is the error I get:

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }

Here is the contract I'm trying to run.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    uint256 public volume;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Oracle: 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8 (Chainlink Devrel   
     * Node)
     * Job ID: d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() public {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        //oracle = 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8; //Kovan
        //jobId = "d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747"; //kovan
        //fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job) //kovan
        
        oracle = 0x63B72AF260E8b40A7b89E238FeB53448A97b03D2;  // BSC Testnet
        jobId = "e07f08e39d2c448d9696319bae8eeddf";  // BSC Testnet
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job) // BSC Testnet
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
   function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        
        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {"RAW":
        //   {"ETH":
        //    {"USD":
        //     {
        //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
        //     }
        //    }
        //   }
        //  }
        request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    
      //Receive the response in the form of uint256
      
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        volume = _volume;
    }
    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
}
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: have you funded your contract with LINK before making the request?

Comment: funding the contract comes after the deployment, I cannot able to deploy it in the first place.

Comment: can you try remove the setPublicChainlinkToken(); line in the constructor, and just manually set the link token contract address? You can get it from the docs https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/